# next js production deploy 404 error on sub pages

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i have deployed code on production for next js build, i have used this command

```
next export -o outDir
```

and uploaded my build code to production, i can see only home page is working, when i tried `/login` it gives me 404 error, can anyone please help me how to resolve this issue ? here i have also attached code for my next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    exportPathMap: async function (
      defaultPathMap,
      { dev, dir, outDir, distDir, buildId }
    ) {
      return {
        '/': { page: '/' },
        '/login': { page: '/login' },
        '/chat': { page: '/chat' },
      }
    },
  }
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using exportPathMap? You usually make use of it if the export file structure is different from the file path you have in /pages. Could you try removing the function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go to `/login.html` instead of `/login`.